# Calculate hours and minutes from end date and current date in laravel blade?

Tags: laravel

I want to calculate hours and minutes from end date(stored in my table) and current date in laravel blade.

My blade:

```
{{\Carbon\Carbon::parse($data['end_date'])->diffForHumans(null, null, null,2)}}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $end_date = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($data['end_date']);
        $start_date = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($data['start_date']);


        $value = $end_date->diff($start_date,2)->format(' %D days  %H hours - %I minutes');
```

for more details see:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php

Comment: It gives me 00:00:00 for last row